# How does Spivak Calculus prove that functions are equal to their Taylor Series?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

I have read through Spivak's Calculus, however I am stuck on one detail. Spivak has shown that Taylor series have radii of convergence, and then gives useful formulae for certain common functions such as exp, sin, ... etc. However, I've had a hard time finding where he explicitly shows that these functions are equal to their series in the radius of convergence.

Comment: In chapter 20 Spivak calculates the Taylor polynomials and bound for the residues for those functions. In chapter 23 he notices that the residues tends to $0$ so the polynomials converges to series which represents the functions.

Comment: Note that many smooth (infinitely differentiable) functions are *not* equal to their Taylor series. For instance, let f : ℝ → ℝ be defined as f(x) = 0 for x ≤ 0 and f(x) = exp(-1/x) for x > 0. All derivatives of f at x = 0 are equal to 0, so the Taylor series of f about x = 0 is the 0 series. This series has an infinite radius of convergence but is unequal to f(x) for all x > 0.